# Cannot get an email to fire in my Jenkins pipeline

Tags: email, jenkins

I'm dipping my toe into the world of Jenkins pipelines.

My aim is to run a simple script that runs a simple command in linux bash and then sends an email when the script has finished. Here is my script:

```
pipeline {
agent any


stages {
    stage('Stage-One') {
        steps {
            script {
                sh "echo 'hi'"

            }
        }
    }
}


post {
    always {
            script {
                emailext body: 'A Test Email', 
                recipientProviders: [[$class: 'DevelopersRecipientProvider'], [$class: 'RequesterRecipientProvider']],
                to: "example@server.com", 
                subject: 'Test'
            }
    }
}
}
```

In my case, I have set my work email as my email under the `E-mail Notification` setting in `Jenkins` -> `Configuration`. I use the same email for firing emails in other Jenkins projects (i.e. running python script/projects) so this should work. In practice, however, no email is received and looking at the email account sending the email shows that no email was sent.

No errors appear in the console output either, but there is no message indicting a success either:

```
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Stage-One)
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ echo hi
hi
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Declarative: Post Actions)
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] emailext
Sending email to: example@server.com
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

My Jenkins version is 2.150.1 and the email extension version is 2.63. Can anyone outline where the problem may be here? It's weird I am getting no error whatsoever.*

Answer (score 1):

Try this trick of defining the body before the emailext

```
def emailBody = 'A Test Email'
def emailSubject = "Test"
emailext(mimeType: 'text/html', replyTo: 'xxxx', subject: emailSubject, to: 'xxxx', body: emailBody)
```

Comment: I inserted your sample into the script tag in my above sample and ran. It runs successfully but still no email is being received. The console output still says "Sending email to:..." with no additional message showing success.